# H2 Database vs SQLite on Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, embedded-database, h2

Because of the [lack of Unicode support on the embedded SQLite database in Android](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9199)

I am mostly interested in performance and stability of [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/) vs Android [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Are you guys using it?
Should I be aware of any H2 database shortcomings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Things are much better than I have expected. I now have an Android phone (HTC Desire, Android 2.2) and I made a first test.

Opening and closing a database is relatively slow so far (opening an existing database for the second time takes 0.2 seconds, closing about 0.2 seconds), but otherwise it looks like H2 performs quite well on Android, even if the Dalvik VM is not yet as optimized as a desktop JVM. It's too early to give concrete numbers, but Android is now a supported platform.

Comment: Hi Thomas, can you provide a link or tutorial to integrate H2 database with android and to start using it.

Comment: There is no step-by-step tutorial, the only documentation is http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#android

Comment: I have read it, only after that I'm searching for a tutorial, also I've posted one question regarding this, kindly have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204785/integrate-h2-database-with-android