# Integrate H2 database with Android

Tags: android, h2

Is there any tutorial for integrating H2 database with Android and to start working on it?
I'm searching for guide to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: and you don't want to use sqlite because...?

Comment: because I need to run database server in Android itself.

Comment: You should create a ContentProvider backed by a SQLite database instead of trying to run a separate database server on the device: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: hi elevine, what if I want to store data from another device, is it possible using ContentProvider?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I've generated jarSmall and included that in my Android project, is it possible to start the server from Android or is there anything that I've to do more?

Comment: what device are you running on?

Comment: Android. Are you asking for exact model?

Comment: Type safety would be another reason to use H2, IIUC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Android documentation in H2](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#android) is the only documentation I know about.