# Get data between date range in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, between

I am trying to get data between date range.
Date is saved as TEXT in my database (dd-MM-YYYY format)
When I fire the below query results are null.

```
SELECT * FROM appointment_table WHERE date BETWEEN cast( '08-02-2017' as datetime ) AND cast( '16-02-2017' as datetime ) AND barber_id = 36
```

The correct way for getting data between date ranges when date is saved in TEXT format irrespective of the date format is as below

```
SELECT * FROM appointment_table WHERE date BETWEEN '08-02-2017' AND '16-02-2017' AND barber_id = 36
```

Comment: You're casting your range to datetime, but the column date is still a TEXT. Probably doesn't make sense

Comment: Look at the response in this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207494/android-sqlite-select-between-date1-and-date2

Comment: I think you need to change the date to be '2017-02-08'

Comment: @MaheshwariReddy Have you run in SQL to check that is it returning any data ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use one of the format supported by SQLite described here to use BETWEEN:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

So your query should become: (transform DD-MM-YYYY strings to YYYY-MM-DD date)

```
SELECT * FROM appointment_table WHERE barber_id = 36 AND (date BETWEEN '2017-02-08' AND '2017-02-16')
```