# how can i fix this error?(1) near "AND": syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

```
        String selectQuery = "select * from " + TABLE+"where"+cur_date+"BETWEEN start_date AND end_date";
        sqlDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

error :::::::::::::
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "AND": syntax error

```
         [ 02-17 10:59:17.504 24925:24925 W/         ]
         [ColorAdjust] gammamode=2, cemode=11


         [ 02-17 10:59:17.504 24925:24925 W/         ]
         [ColorAdjust] temp_gammavalue=2, temp_cevalue=11


         [ 02-17 10:59:17.504 24925:24925 W/         ]
         [ColorAdjust] Don't setGamma!


         [ 02-17 10:59:17.504 24925:24925 W/         ]
         [ColorAdjust] Don't setCe!


         [ 02-17 10:59:17.514 24925:24925 W/         ]
         [ColorAdjust] Set temp_prefer temp_ce!
```

how can i solve it.please anyone help me...

Comment: Improve your query its wrong.

Comment: Check out here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207494/android-sqlite-select-between-date1-and-date2

Comment: Add proprer space between all words like your like this
"select * from " + TABLE+" where "+cur_date+" BETWEEN start_date AND end_date";

Answer (score 1):

Add proper spaces between the words and check for the correct query:

Try this:

```
"select * from "+TABLE+" where "+cur_date+" BETWEEN '"+start_date+"' AND '"+end_date+"' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

update the above stated code with

```
String selectQuery = "select * from " + TABLE + " where " + cur_date +" BETWEEN start_date AND end_date";
sqlDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
```