# How to select records where date is between date1 and date2?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseProvider.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + ConsumerEnquiryTable.TABLE_NAME + " where "
            + ConsumerEnquiryTable.Cols.USER_LOGIN_ID + "='" + userId + "' AND ( CAST("
            + ConsumerEnquiryTable.Cols.DUE_DATE + " as datetime) >= CAST(" + beginDate  +
            " as datetime) AND CAST(" + ConsumerEnquiryTable.Cols.DUE_DATE + " as datetime) <= CAST("+ endDate + " as datetime)) AND "
            + ConsumerEnquiryTable.Cols.CARD_STATUS + "='" + jobCardStatus + "'", null);
```

I have tried with CAST, strftime, datetime.
The due_date column is of varchar type and i want to select records having  due_date between beginDate and endDate. All the dates are of dd/MM/yyyy format

Comment: Please elaborate on your question and add further details. Please avoid posting code-only content. Please make use of the SO formatting features and post your code as "code".

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207494/android-sqlite-select-between-date1-and-date2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the column's `DUE_DATE` format to `YYYY-MM-DD`, which is the only comparable format for SQLite, then all you need is a `BETWEEN` clause and pass all the arguments as a string array, which is the recommended safest way to avoid any risk of sql injection:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM " + ConsumerEnquiryTable.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + 
    ConsumerEnquiryTable.Cols.USER_LOGIN_ID + " = ? AND (" +
    ConsumerEnquiryTable.Cols.DUE_DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND " +
    ConsumerEnquiryTable.Cols.CARD_STATUS + " = ?", 
    new String[] {userId, beginDate, endDate, jobCardStatus}
);
```

Of course the arguments beginDate and endDate must also be in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query

```
mDb.query(MY_TABLE, null, DATE_COL + " BETWEEN ? AND ?", new String[] {
                minDate + " 00:00:00", maxDate + " 23:59:59" }, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: returns no records, my date column is of varchar type